Trouble creating react app inside WSL but works on windows
I am able to successfully run npx create-react-app while inside my windows directory. However, I cannot run this inside WSL. Any reason why? Tried more ways than I can count in trying to resolve this.


Firstly, don't use images of text, copy'n'paste the text instead. Then, nobody here knows what you did, because you don't provide any info, only on the outcome. Provide a [mcve], extracted from your code. Maybe also re-take the [tour] and read [ask].

Within your wsl, try finding the directory where you wish to create your project under the path mnt/c/Users/your_user_name.
This corresponds to your mounted drive within wsl, which is not the default path you start at when you launch a cmd.exe.

I see the c folder but I am unable to access it. It shows c inside mnt when I run ls but I can't cd into it. When I try cd c inside of mnt, it says "c: not a directory".

@d1du Try to go into the desired folder in your regular Windows terminal. Then, once you are in the directory you wish to create your React app, type wsl in the terminal to launch wsl. That should mount the path to your folder. Once wsl is running, check the path to make sure in was mounted correctly, should be something like this mnt/c/Users/your_user_name/your_react_dir
